# Displaying multiple items from same array, that have different metadata

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

In Wordpress I am trying to display data in a loop. In this particular loop I want to include all items that have the following meta-data:

```
red
blue
green
```

I have the following array:

```
      $posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'people',
    'meta_key' => 'role',
    'meta_compare' => '=',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_value' => 'red',
    )
  );
```

This displays items that are `red` just fine. But how to add to the array so it shows all items?

The function code is here:

```
      if($posts)
          {     ?>

        <h3 class="col-md-12">Red & Blue & Green</h3>
    <?php
            foreach($posts as $post)
            {
              ?>           
                <div class="thumb-frame col-md-3 col-xs-6 pull-right">
                  <a href="#detail<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>" onClick="showDetail('<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>');">
                    <figure class="thumb">
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php the_field('portrait_image');?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
                      <figcaption>
                        <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                      </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                  </a>
                </div>
              <?php
      $num++;
    }        
          }      
        ?>
```

I am new to PHP and am unsure of syntax, but should there be an OR operator, or perhaps a nested array?

Comment: You mention that you have numerous loops in a comment bellow. Read [**When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a WordPress developer, but I'm guessing you can get those posts by retrieving 3 sets of posts from the database:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'people',
    'meta_key' => 'role',
    'meta_compare' => '=',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_value' => 'red',
));

$posts += get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'people',
    'meta_key' => 'role',
    'meta_compare' => '=',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_value' => 'blue',
));

$posts += get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'people',
    'meta_key' => 'role',
    'meta_compare' => '=',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_value' => 'green',
));
```

Now the `$posts` array will contain a Union of the 3 results.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but the $post variable just gets overwritten with each iteration of the array

Comment: Hey @PeteNorris, not it wouldn't, you need to use $posts += and not $posts = . It's a basic PHP operator on arrays, try it.

Comment: It only returns values for the first array

Comment: That's weird, try using 3 arrays to get the 3 data sets then using array_merge to concatenation them

Comment: Or maybe it's just returning red values because that's all that exists in the database

Comment: No, I have testing for each value and they return - just not together! Another poster mentioned the issue might be because I have other loops on the same page?

Comment: Possibly, you have to get the $posts data before the loops, and make sure you're just reading from it in the loop

Comment: I think you last suggestion is a good one, although I have no idea how to go about it. This has become a bit bigger than the original question, but thanks for your help all same.

Comment: Hi, I'm sure you're doing something wrong, check http://in2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php, you'll see that the + operator does result in the union of 2 arrays. I'm pretty sure the above code works perfectly well. The $posts array above will have the entire set required. The problem is definitely somewhere else in your code. Maybe you can post more of your code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'people',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
         'key'=>'role', 
         'value'=>array('red', 'blue', 'green'), 
         'compare'=>'OR'
    )

  )
);
```

Take a look on [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: This is returning everything... even items with values of 'yellow' ' purple' etc

Answer (score 0):

Try it using  change query, it might help you

```
query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'people',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'role',
            'value' => 'red',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'role',
            'value' => 'blue',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
) );
```

[Reference from scribu](http://scribu.net/wordpress/advanced-metadata-queries.html)

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
     echo "<h3 class="col-md-12">Red & Blue & Green</h3>";
     while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        **// Your loop code**

    }
else {
    echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
}
?>
```

Comment: This makes sense, but I cannot get it to return anything.

Comment: @PeteNorris answer is edited.Try with replace looping.

Comment: Thanks for trying - "Sorry, no posts were found"

Comment: ohh so please insert post first

Comment: I don't understand... there are posts. If I run the code in my example at the top it returns a post.

Comment: is any other loop running on same page ?

Comment: Yes... There are numerous loops

Comment: add <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> before query post. or add after numerous loops. it is used when all query are conflict to eachother

Comment: Tried the reset, alas no joy.
I think a post below had the best suggestion of extracting the array into variables, then calling those in the post - although no idea how that would be achieved. thanks all. I think this has outgrown the original question.